# Oracle roles & privileges for trigger creation

Tags: oracle, security

What Oracle roles/privileges do I need to create a trigger on a table in another schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"in another schema?"

CREATE ANY TRIGGER. However, like any ANY privilege, it is **VERY** dangerous so a DBA is unlikely to give it to you.

The DBA could create that trigger for you or maybe give you the password to that schema to create the trigger there.

Answer (score -1):

```
GRANT CREATE TRIGGER TO user_class;
```

Comment: Doesn't cover the 'In another schema"